# SSRS Configuration Error; Invalid PBI Configuration

Tags: reporting-services, configuration

I got this issue on one of my machines when I installed MSSQL Server 2016 with SSIS, SSAS and SSRS.

SSIS and SSAS is working fine but SSRS does not.

After the installation, I opened the Reporting Services Configuration Manager and leave everything to default. This usually the end of it, but for some reason when opening the Portal, I got this:

[image: Error on Web]

When I check the log, the error is

```
ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: Invalid PBI Configuration, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
```

What is **Invalid PBI Configuration**? And how do I identify the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: PBI is Power BI integration a new feature in SSRS 2016. It's an option during initial Server install. If you are not using this then you should just be able to disable it in the SSRS configuration.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Unfortunately its merely a symptom, because once I cleared that issue a new ERROR shows up in the log. I have decided to install everything from fresh as this machine is supposed to be.

Answer (score 4):

Took a while to sort this out, but it's a simple fix.

1. Open SQL Server Reporting Services Configuration Manager
2. Click on Web Service URL menu and make sure that the URL's match the ones located in Web Portal URL menu.
3. If they're different, open the rsreportserver.config file (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer) and remove any entries not listed in Web Service URL.
4. Open your web portal ie. http://localhost/Reports and see if it's resolved.  If so, all done.
5. If not, click the Encryption Keys menu, in the "Delete Encrypted Content" section, click "Delete".
6. Open your web portal again and see if it's resolved.
7. Locate and update your datasource credentials.

Comment: In step 2. Can you please tell me where in the file I can find the URL. I could not figure it out

Comment: Open Report Server Configuration Manager on your computer, then go to the Web Service URL.